# Prove that for all integers p and n, if p is prime and p | n^2 then p | n

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing

How to prove the above by contradiction? I have the following so far:

Let p be prime and p|n^2 for intgers p and n.

Suppose $p\nmid n$.

Therefore, we can write n^2 = pb for some integer b.

Hence, p is a prime factor of n^2.

...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $n=p_1^{\alpha _1}\cdot ...\cdot p_k^{\alpha _k}$. Then $$n=p_1^{2\alpha _1}\cdot ...\cdot p_k^{2\alpha _k}$$

If $p\mid n^2$, by Gauss lemma, $p\mid p_i^{2\alpha _i}$ for a certain $i$. Since $p$ is prime, $p=p_i$. The claim follow.